# what is the exactly difference between dto assembler and factory

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

As far as I know, factory is responsible for creating complex entity（Aggregate）in DDD, it may contain some business logic. And factory exists in Domain Layer. At the same time, DTO assembler(usually exists in application layer）can also convert DTO to an Entity(dto assembler is not a concept in DDD).

Now consider a situation: I need to create an aggregate, but the essential information is in DTO(assume it has many attributes), how can factory get the information？As far as I know, DTO should not pass to Domain Layer where factory exists. And I think DTO assembler should not be responsible for creating Aggregate too. How can I do? Or what is the best practice for this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a Memento pattern.

In your domain you add a Memento class, that stores the basic information used to (re)build the entity. The entity itself has at least one function that accepts the Memento instance and returns a newly instance of itself. Maybe another one is useful to export the content into a Memento instance, but this could be not necessary.

Once the Memento class is defined, it could be extended in each sub-context (application layer, infrastructure layer, etc) and its properties could be restored starting from different elements (a DTO, or a DB entity, or a http request - just samples). Then, given that all this elements inherit from the original Memento, each of them could be used to rebuild the instance of the entity.

I know that this adds some 'pollution' to an otherwise clean domain, but the reality is that the code should work in a way that's simple to understand. Adding this pattern doesn't make your domain dirty, but it simplifies a lot the way you restore your entity from a given DTO without too many 'jumps'.